# How do I set up a mock queue using mockrunner to test an xml filter?

Tags: queue, jms, ejb, jndi, mockrunner

I'm using the mockrunner package from http://mockrunner.sourceforge.net/ to set up a mock queue for JUnit testing an XML filter which operates like this:

1. sets recognized properties for an ftp server to put and get xml input and a jms queue server that keeps track of jobs. Remotely there waits a server that actually parses the xml once a queue message is received.
2. creates a remote directory using ftp and starts a queue connection using mqconnectionfactory to the given address of the queue server.
3. once the new queue entry is made in 2), the filter waits for a new queue message to appear signifying the job has been completed by the remote server. The filter then grabs the modified xml file from the ftp and passes it along to the next filter.

The JUnit test I am working on simply needs to emulate this environment by starting a local ftp and mock queue server for the filter to connect to, then waiting for the filter to connect to the queue and put the new xml input file on a local directory via a local ftp server, wait for the queue message and then modify the xml input slightly, put the modified xml in a new directory and post another message to the queue signifying the job has completed.

All of the tutorials I have found on the net have used EJB and JNDI to lookup the queue server once it has been made. If possible, I'd like to sidestep that route by just creating a mock queue on my local machine and connecting to it in the simplest manner possible, not using EJB and JNDI.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I'm using [MockEjb](http://mockejb.sourceforge.net) and there are some examples among them one for using mock queues, so take a look to the [info](http://mockejb.sourceforge.net/javadoc/index.html) and to the [example](http://mockejb.sourceforge.net/java2html/org/mockejb/test/MDBTest.java.html)
Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend having a look at using [Apache Camel](http://activemq.apache.org/camel/) to create your test case. Then its really easy to switch your test case from any of the [available components](http://activemq.apache.org/camel/components.html) and most importantly Camel comes with some really handy [Mock Endpoints](http://activemq.apache.org/camel/mock.html) which makes it super easy to test complex routing logic particularly with asynchronous operations.

If you also use Spring, then maybe start by trying out these [Spring unit tests with mock endpoints in Camel](http://activemq.apache.org/camel/spring-testing.html) which let you inject the mock endpoints to perform assertions on together with the ProducerTemplate object to make it really easy to fire your messages for your test case. e.g. see the last example on that page.

Start off using simple endpoints like the [SEDA endpoint](http://activemq.apache.org/camel/seda.html) - then when you've got your head around the core spring/mock framework, try using the [JMS endpoint](http://activemq.apache.org/camel/jms.html) or [FTP endpoint](http://activemq.apache.org/camel/ftp.html) endpoints etc.